# Reordering overlays of GMSMapView

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm adding several GMSOverlays (specifically GMSPolylines) to my GMSMapView. On certain occasions (taps) I now want to reorder them s.t. a new polyline appears to be on top of all others. Is there any way to change the order of the overlays added to a GMSMapView?

I've already tried removing the overlay and adding it again by doing

```
overlay.map = nil;
overlay.map = mapView;
```

but that doesn't do the trick.

Thanks for any help!

P.S.: I'm using version 1.2.2 of the Google Maps SDK for iOS.

Comment: There is a feature request to be able to change the order of overlays here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5294

Answer (score 2):

The Z-index feature is part of the google maps sdk for ios **Version 1.4.0 - July 2013**

Features list mentions:

```
Added a zIndex property on all overlays. Z-Indexes are calculated in two groups: GMSMarkers and all other overlays.
```